# How to get value from query localhost:8000/example?q={"user":"admin"} in golang

Tags: mongodb, go

I have data from database:

```
[{ 
    "name": "joseph",
    "user": "admin"
},
{   "name": "george",
    "user": "visitor"
},
{
    "name": "thomas",
    "user": "admin"
}]
```

I want to find with user with url, example: ../testing?q={"user":"admin"}

then result data only admin.

Comment: What have you tried? Include your code. What problems did you encounter?

Answer (score 0):

First of all your query string should follow format mentioned in this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string

```
// r is *http.Request
r.URL.Query().Get("user")  // this will provide the value of user in the query
```

This should be sufficient for your use case but for more details you can refer to https://golangbyexample.com/net-http-package-get-query-params-golang